# Non-constant index in a synthesizable Verilog deserializer

Tags: fpga, verilog, synthesis

I would like to represent a Deserializer 4096 to 4 in a more efficient way than declaring a counter and assigning sequentially the 1024 cases.

I have faced errors in trying to assign a non-constant index and making it synthesizable.

Is there a more efficient way to do it than declare the multiple cases?

Below is my proposal

```
module DESER_FIFO4096
#(parameter WIDTH_INPUT=4096, WIDTH_OUTPUT=4)
 (
input       clk,
input       [WIDTH_INPUT-1:0] PI,
input       rst,
output      [WIDTH_OUTPUT-1:0] SO,
);

reg [WIDTH_OUTPUT-1:0]  data_ff;
reg [9:0]       cnt;
assign SO   =   data_ff;
always @(posedge clk)
    begin
        if (rst)
            begin
                data_s  <= {{WIDTH_OUTPUT}{1'b0}};
                cnt         <= {{WIDTH_OUTPUT}{1'b0}};
                
            end
        else 
            begin
        
                case(cnt)
                    10'd0    :    data_s<=PI[3:0];                      
                    10'd1    :    data_s<=PI[7:4];                      
                ... 
                ... 
                    10'd1023 :    data_s<=PI[4095:4092];
                endcase                 
                cnt         <= cnt +    1'd1;
               end
            end
   endmodule
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

While it is not possible to use a variable index inside the standard `[:]` parts select, because you could declare different widths, there is the indexed part select operator `[+:]` (and `[-:]` which do allow this.

For example, `data_s<=PI[0+:4]`, would be equivalent to saying "Take four bits counting upwards, starting with bit 0" (or equivalent `PI[3-:4]`, four bits from 3, counting downward).

With this you can start using variables:

```
data_s <= PI[(cnt * 4) +:4]
```

The `*4` here is not expensive because it converts directly to `{cnt, 2'b00}`. By stating the width must always be `4` we also avoid any synthesis issues. This will infer a large multiplexer, or rather four of them (one for each output bit).

---

Alternatively, you could use a for loop to generate the same thing, allowing you to specify a defined end point which may help with your parameterisation:

```
for (i = 0; i < WIDTH_INPUT/4; i = i + 1) begin
    if (cnt == i) begin
        data_s <= PI[(4*i) +: 4];
    end
end
```